# Can I scale a mesh with baked physics?

Tags: edit-mode, cloth-simulation

I'm having a lot of troubles with a cloth simulation for a flag flapping in the wind and I'm starting to suspect that my problems are related to small scale at which I'm running the simulation (length of the flag is 0.04 Blender units).

Is it possible to bake the simulation at a more typical size, then scale down to my mini-flag? Alternatively, are there tricks one can play to work around problems with simulating physics with really small objects?

Comment: imho the bake can't be scaled, but maybe you can describe a bit what  "lot of troubles" means, which undesired behaviour you get, so that others could help you better there

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have to work at such a small scale?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. If for some reason it doesn't, you should be able to parent it to an Empty and scale the Empty (the child object will inherit the scale). I don't have a machine in front of me to test on right now, but why don't you go ahead and try.

Comment: @Mentalist I tried, and after baking the sim, you can scale (object or edit mode) the original base object but the baked animation will keep same scale as before... the bake keeps its own scale. It needs to be baked again after scaling.

Comment: @cegaton I have a mix of some really large objects and some really small objects

Answer (score 2):

Here a workaround if someone else encounters this issue in the future:

Simply bake your animation and export it as albemic file (.abc). The animation playback will be slower, but as you import the albemic file you will find a transform cache in the constraints tab. In the transform cache you can simply scale and offset your animation to your likings.

Comment: Exactly! In any scenario where you need to somehow permanently cache your animated mesh, Alembic is the way to go most of the time. Downsize is you can't keep materials with it (but you can write UVs and materials' assignation areas, so you can reassign them later on). These days the VFX industry's pipelines relie heavily on caching every mesh data into alembic when sending down to each department.